# On table append row Select2 don't handle events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, jquery-select2

I need insert dynamically rows in table with select2, and use select2:select event but this event not work on the added select2, only in the original.
I'm tryed diferent methods but nothing solved the issue with the event. 
I'm have no more details.
El Maestruli se reiria.

CODE:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('main-content')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" >
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background: #222d32   ; color: #FFFFFF;  opacity: 0.9;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="float: left;">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="margin-top: 10px;">Gestionar proveedores</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8" style="float: right;">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/admin/proveedores/nuevo" style="float: right;">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nuevo</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" name="tabla" id="tabla">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:25%">Codigo de barras</th>
                        <!--<th style="width:25%">Modelo</th>
                        <th style="width:30%">Serial</th>-->
                        <th>Accion</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row1">
                        <td><select data-ex="asd" class="form-control" name="codbarras" id="select_1"></select></td>
                        <!--<td><select name="modelo" class="form-control" id="modelo_1" disabled></select></td>
                        <td><select name="serial" class="form-control" id="serial_1"></select></td>-->
                        <td><input class="btn btn-success" tabindex="1" type="button" name="add"  id="add_1" value="+"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tabla-filtro" width="100%" id="tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="POST" action="/admin/proveedores/eliminar" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background: #4682B4; color: #FFFFFF;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="titulo"> Deshabilitar area</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="help-block">¿Esta seguro que desea deshabilitar este proveedor?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Eliminar">

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Script for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_1').select2({
        placeholder: 'ppp',
        data:[{
            id:1,
            text:'asd'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            text: 'asdasd'
        }]
    });
})

$('#add_1').on('click',function(){
    $('#select_1').select2("destroy");
    $('#tabla').append('<tr><td><select data-ex="asd" name="testing" id="select_2"></select></td></tr>');
    $('#select_1').select2();
    $('#select_2').select2({
        placeholder: 'ppp',
        data:[{
            id:1,
            text:'asd'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            text: 'asdasd'
        }]
    });
});

$('[data-ex="asd"]').on("select2:select",function(e){
    alert('work');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refresh your select2 event after inserting rows

Put the event in a function and call it where you previously declarated it at the end of the click event.